# Navigation issues in fragment backstack

Tags: android, navigationbar

Multiple taps on bottom navigation bar does not happens as expected

bottom bar has 5 tabs

every tab selection pops the tag and pushes the tag

tap on Fragment A--> tap on Fragment B, repeat the same to two to five times.

ex:

Tap A
--> Pops A from stack
--> push A to Stack 
Tap B
--> pop B from Stack 
--> push B to stack

behaviour:
by default A fragment is loaded, on tap of B navigating to B, later tap on A goes to A, here when back presses app closed.

expected :
result should be something like this
by default A fragment is loaded, on tap of B navigating to B, later tap on A goes to A, here when back pressed it should go to B and backpress goto A then backpress close the app.

```
case FragmentA: 
    fragmenta = new FragmentA();

    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(FragmentReferenceTags.FragmentA, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); // returns False - can't find the tag!

    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_layout, fragmenta, FragmentReferenceTags.FragmentA);
    transaction.addToBackStack(FragmentReferenceTags.FragmentA);

    transaction.commit();
    hideSubTabs();
    break;

case FragmentB:
    fragmentb = new FragmentB();

    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(FragmentReferenceTags.FragmentB, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); // returns False - can't find the tag!

    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_layout, fragmentb, FragmentReferenceTags.FragmentB);
    transaction.addToBackStack(FragmentReferenceTags.FragmentB);

    transaction.commit();
    hideSubTabs();
    break;
```

Comment: Please navigate a bit SO and Google. there are thousands of questions like this. I tell you this because I've already found 5-10 copy of this question in last 1-2 months.

Comment: Thank you for your time Misley, i had spent enough time on doing research on this point where i could not get any helpful solution. if you could paste me an URL stating the same i can go through it once and find for a solution.

Comment: got a question: your fragments A, B,... are the tabs of your bottomTabBar or all in the same tab?

Comment: they are the tabs of bottom bar

Comment: you have to handle it manually overriding the back button

Comment: which is what am doing already, here the problem is as the popbackstack will pop the stack entries till the tag finds, in this process it is popping the 3rd , 4th tab entries when we pop the entry of 2nd tab for second time, which is why it goes to 1st while back pressed where it supposed to go to 3rd and 1st.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` instead of `add` :

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_layout, fragmentb, FragmentReferenceTags.FragmentB);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. No luck with replace too tried it already and even now..it is the same behaviour ..i can't pass the null to backstack cause am using those tags for bottom navigation bar selection on back press